# Two combinatorics questions im not sure about

Tags: combinatorics

i have those two qusetions and there is no final answer so i dont know if im right or no.

> **First Question:** there are 6 horse stands, and there are 4 horses:
> (a) How many ways are there to have two
> stands with exactly 2 horses
> (b) How many ways are there for exactly
> 3 stands to be empty?
> (c) That there will be horses in exactly 2
> stands

**my solution:**
**(a)** $C(4,2)* 6 * 1 * C(2,1) * 5* 1 $ - im choosing 2 horses from 4 and then first horse have 6 stands to go, 2nd horse have 1 position because i want him in the same stand with the first horse, then i choose 1horse from the two i have left and he have 5 stands to choose from and the last horse must go same stand with this (3rd)horse.
**(b)** $C(4,1) * 6 * C(3,1) * 5 * C(2,1) * 4 * 3 $ - im thinking about it as how many ways there are exactly 3 stands with horses, and then its same concept as (a)
**(c)** $C(4,3) * 6 * C(1,1) * 5 + C(4,2)*6*C(2,1)*5$ - its either 3:1 or 2:2(same as (a))

> **Second Qeustion:** In an electrical store, there are 3 types of air conditioners, during an inventory check it turned out that there are 4
> different air conditioners from company **A**, 5 Different air
> conditioners from company **B** and 10 different air conditioners from
> company **C**.   a person enters the store and chooses at random (and
> without return) 4 air conditioners.
> **(a)** the sample he chose will have air conditioners from the three companies?
> **(b)** that the sample will have air conditioners from only two companies?

**my solution:**
**(a)** isn't it just $4 * 5 * 10 * 16$ because i want him to choose one from **A** one from **B** one from **C** and one from what is left?
**(b)** $4*5*C(7,2)+4*10*C(12,2)+5*10*C(13,2)$ - choosing one from company **A** one from company **B** and then 2 from **A** and **B** combined and so on with **A,C** and **B,C**

Comment: Part $(a)$ doesn't read right. "(a) How many ways are there to have two stands with exactly 2 horses." To me, in English this asks, "If two horses exist, then how many ways are there to have two stands ? ". This is weird. Maybe it was meant to be, "How many ways are there to have two stands, **each** with exactly 2 horses." But even then, it is not clear which of the following two questions was meant: "How many different ways can you have exactly two horses in exactly two stands ?", or, "How many different ways can you have exactly two horses in at least two stands ?"

Comment: sry mb i didnt translate it the best so there are 4 horses and 6 stands, every horse must go/have a stand so in how many different ways can you have exactly two horses in exactly two stands

Comment: And a stand can have more than one horse? Ok well that makes sense and is answerable. Please amend your question.

Comment: The information that there are four horses should be included in the question.   The question cannot be answered without knowing that.

Comment: @David it should be there are four horses, shouldn't  it?

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo yes, i edited thank you

Comment: Please ask only *one* question per post.  Also, when you ask a question please try to go a little further than simply posting the question and your attempt and asking (essentially) "what's wrong with this?"  If you think that your solution is incorrect, please try to point out *where* your confusion is.  If you think that your solution is correct, then this is likely not the right place to post your question---this site is not designed as a homework checking service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\underline{\text{Soapbox}}$

I'll discuss your mistakes for part (1a), but that doesn't address the underlying problem.  You, the OP, (i.e. original poster) haven't received proper training to attack Combinatorics problems.  If you are in the middle of a class/book, then I suggest that you print out your work and show it to your instructor.

Your instructor should then realize that your intuition has not yet developed.  Alternatively, if this isn't part of a book/class, then I suggest not trying to tackle these types of problems, at this time.

You don't ask a medical student to do surgery, on day 1.

Instead, I suggest that you find the right book on Combinatorics for you.  The book should have many, many exercises for you to work through.  Then, I suggest that you open the book to page 1, and attack.

---

$\underline{\text{Part (1a)}}$

Your work in part (a) is wrong.  Consider the situation where horse-1,horse-2 goes in stall-1, and horse-3,horse-4, goes in stall-2.  You counted this situation twice: once when you pick stall-1 first, and then stall-2 second, and once when you pick stall-2 first, and then stall-1 second.

A safer way to approach this is to reason that there are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} = 15 ~$ ways to select the horse stalls.

So, you *reserve* the factor of $~15,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality that stall-1 and stall-2 have been chosen.

Part (1a), does not specify how many horses there are to choose from, when you are selecting the four horses.  So, absent that information, in order to complete part (1a), I am forced to assume that there are exactly four horses.

Now, you have to select two of the four horses, to put in stall-1, and then the two remaining horses will go in stall-2.

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} = 6~$ ways of determining which two of the $~4~$ horses will go in stall-1.

So, the answer to part(1a) is

$$\binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} = 15 \times 6 = 90.$$

---

For the remainder of the problems, I will simply answer the questions.  Leave a comment after the answer, if you have questions about my work, or want me to dissect a specific part of your analysis.

---

$\underline{\text{Part (1b)}}$

Part (1b) is a much more difficult problem.

First, you have to determine which $~3~$ stalls will be used.  There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{3} = 20 ~$ ways of selecting the $~3~$ stalls to be used.

So, you reserve the factor of $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{3} = 20,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality that stall-1, stall-2, and stall-3 will be used.

At this point, the assumption that there are only $~4~$ horses makes the problem easier than it might have been.

The only satisfying distribution of the horses is $~2 : 1 : 1.$

There are $~\displaystyle ~\binom{4}{2} = 6~$ ways of determining which two of the horses will be together.

So, reserve the second factor of $~\displaystyle ~\binom{4}{2} = 6,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality that horse-1 and horse-2 will be together.

Now comes the tricky part.  Assume that you will put horse-1 + horse-2 in whichever stall you happen to first select.  Then assume that you will put horse-3 in the second stall that you happen to select, and horse-4 in the last stall that you happen to select.

Then, the distribution of the horses, under the assumption that horse-1 and horse-2 go together will be completely dependent on the order that you select the $~3~$ stalls, stall-1, stall-2, and stall-3.

There are $~3! = 6~$ ways of *permuting* the $~3~$ stalls, to determine the order that the stalls will be selected.

Putting it all together, the answer to part (1b) is

$$\binom{6}{3} \times \binom{4}{2} \times 3! = 20 \times 6 \times 6 = 720.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Part (1c)}}$

This particular problem is (in some ways), even more advanced.

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} = 15~$ ways of determining which $~2~$ stalls will be used.

So, reserve the factor of $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} = 15,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality, that stall-1 and stall-2 will be used.

Now, you have to split the problem into two cases:

- The horses will be split 3::1.
  If they are split 3::1, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1}~$ ways of determining which horse will be alone.  Then, there are $~2~$ choices for which stall receives the lone horse.
  The computation here is $~\binom{4}{1} \times 2 = 4 \times 2 = 8.$
- The horses will be split 2::2.
  This situation is very tricky.  Horse-1 has three choices for which other horse to partner with.  Then, Horse-1 and its partner have two choices for which stall receives them.
  The computation here is $~3 \times 2 = 6.$

So, the *partial computation* for the distribution of the horses, once stall-1 and stall-2 have been selected is

$$8 + 6 = 14.$$

Therefore, the overall computation for part (1c) is

$$~\binom{6}{2} \times 14 = 210.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Part (2)}}$

All of part (2) is ambiguous, because it is unspecified whether (for example) different air conditioners from company A are distinguishable from each other.

I will assume that the air conditioners from company A (and other companies) are distinguishable from each other.

In fact, this assumption seems necessary, or else the data given on how many air conditioners are supplied by each company would become irrelevant.

---

$\underline{\text{Part (2a)}}$

The only satisfying distribution is 2::1::1.  Then, you have three mutually exclusive cases to consider, depending on which company supplies $~2~$ air conditioners.

- Company A supplies $~2~$ air conditioners.
  Then, the number of possibilities is 
  $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{10}{1} = 6 \times 5 \times 10 = 300.$
- Company B supplies $~2~$ air conditioners.
  Then, the number of possibilities is 
  $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{10}{1} = 4 \times 10 \times 10 = 400.$
- Company C supplies $~2~$ air conditioners.
  Then, the number of possibilities is 
  $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{10}{2} = 4 \times 5 \times 45 = 900.$

So, the computation for part (2a) is

$$300 + 400 + 900 = 1600.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Part (2b)}}$

The only satisfying distributions are 3::1 or 2::2, which must be handled separately.  Further, for each satisfying distribution, you then have the sub-cases of which company supplies how many air conditioners.

For non-negative integers $~r,s,t,~$ 
let the syntax $~[r:s:t]~$ denote that $~r, ~s, ~$ and $~t~$ air conditioners were supplied by company A, company B, and company C, respectively.

The choices are:

- $[3:1:0].$
  $\displaystyle \binom{4}{3} \times \binom{5}{1} = 20.$
- $[3:0:1].$
  $\displaystyle \binom{4}{3} \times \binom{10}{1} = 40.$
- $[1:3:0].$
  $\displaystyle \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{5}{3} = 40.$
- $[1:0:3].$
  $\displaystyle \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{10}{3} = 480.$
- $[0:3:1].$
  $\displaystyle \binom{5}{3} \times \binom{10}{1} = 100.$
- $[0:1:3].$
  $\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{10}{3} = 600.$
- $[2:2:0].$
  $\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{5}{2} = 60.$
- $[2:0:2].$
  $\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{10}{2} = 270.$
- $[0:2:2].$
  $\displaystyle \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{10}{2} = 450.$

So, the overall computation for part (2b) is

$$20 + 40 + 40 + 480 + 100 + 600 \\
+ 60 + 270 + 450 \\
= 2060.$$

Comment: I greatly appreciate the way of your detailed answering. By the way can't you assume that there are enough number of horses to consider all possible cases since number of horses not mentioned in the question. By that way, in part 1 a  you get five different options 0,1,2,3,4  for each of the remaining four stands out of given 6 .

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo In theory, yes, you could make that assumption.  However, there are several reasons why I chose to assume that there are exactly $~4~$ horses.  The first reason is **meta-cheating** : getting into the mind of the problem composer.  If the problem composer wanted to make the number of horses a *variable*, and have different answers based on the value of this variable, then I surmise (perhaps wrongly) that the problem composer would have made that explicit specification.  ...see next comment

Comment: Further, my (very subjective) *sense* of the problem composer's mind was that having the number of horses be a variable would interfere with the educational lesson that the problem composer was going for.  Second, while it was hard to dissect the original poster's work, the impression that I got was that the original poster was making the same assumption.  Since I was trying to communicate with the original poster, I thought it best to create an answer that the original poster could *identify with*.  Actually, in the comments, the original poster confirmed the assumption of 4 horses.

Comment: Thanks, I got it and if the number of horses not given this issue would have been much more complicated with so many options.

Comment: @user2661923 Wow thank you very much for your answer, Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** The question was edited to add information that makes my answer no longer pertinent.

The way the horse question is written, I would interpret it very differently.

Each stand can accomodate up to $4$ horses, which means that each of the six stands can have $0$,$1$,$2$,$3$, or $4$ horses.

The total number of horses is not given, so you are not choosing horses from a larger group. Instead you are simply assigning a certain number of horses to each of the stands. The horses are considered identical - only the number of horses at each stand matters.

> (a) How many ways are there to have two stands with exactly 2 horses

I assume they mean two stands have two horses, and the other four stands have a different number of horses.

There are $\binom{6}{2}=15$ ways to choose which two stands have two horses. The other four stands have $0$,$1$,$3$, or $4$ horses, so there are four possible options for each of those stands. This gives an answer of
$$\binom{6}{2} \cdot \text{(options)}^\text{(stands)}=15\cdot4^4=3840$$

> (b) How many ways are there for exactly 3 stands to be empty?

There are $\binom{6}{3}=20$ ways to choose which three stands are empty. The other three stands have $1$,$2$,$3$, or $4$ horses, so there are four possible options for each of those stands. This gives an answer of
$$\binom{6}{3} \cdot \text{(options)}^\text{(stands)}=20\cdot 4^3=1280$$

> (c) That there will be horses in exactly 2 stands

There are $\binom{6}{2}=15$ ways to choose which two stands are non-empty. These stands have $1$,$2$,$3$, or $4$ horses, so there are four possible options for each of those stands. This gives an answer of
$$\binom{6}{2} \cdot \text{(options)}^\text{(stands)}=15\cdot 4^2=240$$

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, i did forgot to mention that there is exactly 4 horses. appreciate your response it does help me understand furthermore.